# Splitting Python classes in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to split one big class (`UI`) into several smaller ones and I have a problem with accessing the other fields in the rest of GUI.
I created a simple GUI using QT Creator and now I want to program it using PyQt5.
When I split the functions into separate classes and use the `verifyBtn` button I get an error:

```
self.hostname = self.IPInp.text()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'IPInp'
```

If `verify_button` function is in main `UI` class then program works fine. Do you have any idea how the code should look like so I can split the function into another class?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
import os, sys

class ButtonHandler(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def verify_button(self):
        self.hostname = self.IPInp.text()

        response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + self.hostname)
        if response == 0:
            self.verifyBtn.setStyleSheet('QPushButton { color: green;}')
            self.verifyBtn.setText("OK")
        else:
            self.verifyBtn.setStyleSheet('QPushButton { color: red;}')
            self.verifyBtn.setText("NO")

class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()       

        uic.loadUi("Test_gui.ui", self)
        self.vBtn = ButtonHandler()
        self.verifyBtn.clicked.connect(self.vBtn.verify_button)
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = UI()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: IPInp isn't a part of ButtonHandler or QMainWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `__init__-method` of `ButtonHandler` you can pass a reference to `UI` in the following way (if you use `toplevel_ui` for the reference to `UI`)

```
class ButtonHandler(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, toplevel) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.toplevel_ui = toplevel_ui
```

so when you create an instance of `ButtonHandler` from `UI`, you now write

```
self.vBtn = ButtonHandler(self)
```

and then when you want to access properties of the class `UI` from the class `ButtonHandler` you write `self.toplevel_ui.<attribute_name>` where you replace `<attribute_name>` with whatever you want. For example `verifyBtn` or `verify_button`.